# Measuring the maximum and minimum execution time of a specific function

Tags: c, profiling, performance

I am doing some trivial benchmarking of writing x lines of the same text into a file using two methods:

1. Direct fwrite.
2. Make a new thread and communication is done via asynchronous queue (main thread is inserting on one side and the other thread is reading from the other). This method is used to try to minimize slowest writing (due to flushing)

This is a snippet of the code which should give a basic idea of the program:

```
int i;
char * buf;
int buf_size;
double local_start, local_end, global_start, global_end;
double slowest, fastest;
double local_time_difference;

buf = "A string to be printed to a file \n";
buf_size = strlen(buf);
fastest = MAX_WRITE_TIME;
slowest = 0;

logger_init(atoi(argv[1]));


global_start = get_time();
for(i = 0 ; i < 100000000 ; i++) 
{
    local_start = get_time();
    logger_write(buf, buf_size);
    local_end = get_time();

    local_time_difference = local_end-local_start;

    if(local_time_difference < fastest && local_time_difference != 0)
        fastest = local_time_difference;

    if(local_time_difference > slowest)
        slowest = local_time_difference;

    if(i % 10000 == 0)
        usleep(1);
}   
global_end = get_time();



printf("Fastest: %1.9f\nSlowest: %1.9f\nTotal Time: %1.9f\n", fastest, slowest, global_end-global_start);
logger_destroy();
```

Get time procedure returns time in microseconds

```
double get_time()
{
    struct timeval t;
    struct timezone tzp;
    gettimeofday(&t, &tzp);
    return t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec*1e-6;
}
```

Depending on the argument passed to logger_init, logger_write will either directly write to the file or insert it in the queue (size of the queue must not exceed some particular limit). [GAsyncQueue](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) is being used

The method I'm currently using to calculate fastest and slowest write certainly works but my question is: is there a tool or profiler that would do this for me? i.e. give me statistics about each function (maximum, minimum and average call)

Tools that I've tried so far but had no luck with:

- gprof
- Zoom
- Kcachegrind
- VTune

**TL:DR**
I am looking for a tool to give me min, max and average execution time of a particular function, not the overall time taken.

Comment: You could get better accuracy with a higher resolution time function like clock_gettime (assuming linux) or QueryPerformanceCounter on windows

Answer (score -1):

- Use the correct high resolution OS API functions for benchmarking.
- Don't calculate execution times from inside the measurement itself, *especially not* if you are using float numbers.
- Why are you calling a sleep function? Are you trying to force a context switch or some oddity like that? The OS will likely handle such better and more efficient than your program.

Comment: I've used clock_gettime but for some reason I copied the wrong version. You can see that I'm printing to the ninth floating number. Regarding your second point are you suggesting that I store the the results in a data-structure (two arrays?) and do the calculations outside?. As for the sleep I am trying to simulate a real world example (decrease the speed at which messages is received)

Comment: @Lundin This is not an answer to the OP's question, so it should have been posted as a comment and not as an answer.